What is the relationship (if any) between Fnechel-Legendre convex duality and Fourier-Laplace duality?
There is something suspiciously similar between the pairs in convex duality (Fenchel-Legendre transform) and Fourier duality (Fourier-Laplace transform).

The Fenchel duality relates points $x$ on a function whose epigraph is a convex set to the slopes of tangents $x^*$ at those points.
The Legendre transform is often first encountered in classical mechanics where it connects states $x$ and momenta $p$. I also encountered it in classical control where $p$ are dual variables (tangents) of a convex loss that involves backpropagation through time.
The Fourier transform relates functions of position $f(x)$ to functions of wavelength $\hat f(\omega)$, and in quantum mechanics the wavelength $\omega$ has the interpretation of a momentum or energy.

The Fenchel transform from convex analysis and the Legendre transform are the same thing, and this transform is also called the convex conjugate.
This question might ultimately be a duplicate of this one, however, I think how exactly is as yet undetermined (any may itself be a separate question). In math, everything is a Tautology, after all.
Things that are confusing me:
Underlying nature of suspicious coincidences in dual pairs
I understand dimly that for mathematical duality in general, the dual object is often about "moving between", e.g. nodes vs. graph edges, vectors vs. linear forms.
The above linked question mentions that in the context of statistical thermodynamics, convex conjugate pairs seem to be logarithms of Fourier-Laplace pairs (mutatis mutandi). A table of convex-conjugate pairs and Fourier-Laplace pairs share enough similarities that it seems like there is some truly shared algebraic structure here (even if not general). What is the origin, nature, depth, extent of this similarity?
The partial answer links to a paper that outlines how this algebraic similarity can be explained via a saddle-point approximation. This intuition is, however, procedural and there discussed in terms of applications to physics rather than in terms of a deeper algebraic relationship. Perhaps for a practicing mathematician, the last step is immediate. But I am not (exactly) a practicing mathematician, so I feel that this fails to satisfy.
Interpretation of dual variables as momenta?
Somehow, Fenchel-Legendre duality covers (position, momentum) duality in classical mechanics, and Fourier-Laplace duality covers (position, momentum) duality in quantum mechanics.
Gaussians, Quadratic curves:
The most striking example is that the family of Gaussian functions is self-dual under the Fourier-Laplace transform, and the family of quadratic curves is closed under the convex conjugate---the latter simply being the logarithm of the former.
This case almost seems like a coincidence, a special property of $\partial x \tfrac 1 2 x^2 = x$ and $\partial_x \exp(f(x)) = f'(x) \exp(x)$. And perhaps that is the case?
Ordinary vs infimal convolution?
The infemal convolution $f\,\square\,g$ of two convex sets can be obtained by adding their Fenchel-Legendre convex conjugates in the dual space and inverting the transform back in to the primal (state-like) space.
The ordinary convolution $f*g$ can be obtained by multiplying the Fourier-Laplace pairs of the respective functions. Or, when definitions permit, adding the logarithms of these transforms.
To summarize, if the operator $\mathbf F$ is Fenchel-Legendre convex conjugation and $\mathcal F$ is the Fourier-Laplace transform,
$$
\begin{matrix}
\mathbf F[f]     &+ &\mathbf     F[g] &= &\mathbf     F[\,f \,\square\, g\,]
\\
\ln\mathcal F[f] &+ &\ln\mathcal F[g] &= &\ln\mathcal F[\,f *       g\,]
\end{matrix}
$$
Random variables?
The coincidences between these two transforms appear in my life when working with exponential family distributions. Adding independent random variables produces a new random variable whose probability density function (PDF) is a convolution of the two. The characteristic (moment generating) function for a random variable is the Fourier (Laplace) transform of its PDF. The cumulant generating function is the logarithm of this Fourier-Laplace transform. Addition of independent random variables amounts to addition of their cumulant-generating functions.
Does this connect to infemal convolution in a non-superficial way? Maybe something about defining convex sets as level sets of certain PDFs? If one considers indicator sets as uniform distributions, we get infemal convolution as the operator that yields the support of the new distribution produced by summing two random variables. I suppose ordinary and infemal convolution are not that different in their construction. But, is that the beginning and the end of structural similarities?
Indicator functions, tangent slopes; Dirac distributions, pure frequencies?
I can define an indicator function $S_{a}(x)$ for state $a$ as a function that is zero when $a=x_0$ and $+\infty$ otherwise. (Check my work, but i think that...) The conjugate of this is a line with slope $a$ (or a family of lines with this slope parametrized by their y-intercepts), $y=ax$.
I can define a Dirac distribution $\delta_a(x)$ centered on $a$ as the zero-variance limit of a Gaussian distribution with mean $a$. It's Laplace transform is $\exp(-as)$, with negative logarithm $-\ln\mathcal L_x[\dots](s) = as$.
Is there a geometric interpretation of evaluating a Fenchel-Legnedre convex conjugate for an imaginary argument?
The Fourier transform can be viewed as evaluating the Laplace transform at $s = i\omega$ imaginary arguments. One can do the same for the Fenchel-Legnedre convex conjugate, but is it always well-posed? Does it mean anything? Does it provide further intuition for why a complex sinusoid is something like a tangent slope (velocity, momentum)?
Concluding remarks
I realize this isn't a well-scoped question beyond "tell me everything about the abstract algebraic and geometric interpretations of duality as they intersect both the Fourier-Laplace and Fenchel-Legendre senses"
Maybe I can summarize this as:

When is there a tight relationship between Fourier-Laplace and Fenchel-Legendre duality? Is it only surface deep?
If this exists only for certain functions, does this class have a name? What is its algebraic structure? Geometric interpretation?
What do we get if we lift intuition/results from one sense of duality to the other? Especially in cases where these tools have physical intuition e.g. physics, signal decompostion, probability theory?

My current intuition is limited to this:

The connection may be exact when considering carefully normalized limit objects for which the $L_2$ (Fourier, Laplace) and $L_0$, $L_\infty$ norms behave similarly, in which case Fourier-Laplace pairs perhaps can be mapped to a subset of Fenchel-Legendre pairs?
The Gaussian/quadratic case may be an epiphenomenon of these families being self-dual in their respective cases and uniquely "central", and connected to the sense in which spaces defined with the L2 norm are self dual?

